# Prove an inequality on $L^p$ space. Looks like Markov inequality, but not

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $f$ and $g$ be two positive measurable functions such that $$\mu(f\geq\epsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\{f\geq\epsilon\}}g\,d\mu$$ for all $\epsilon\geq0$. Show that for any $1<p<\infty$, $$\lVert f\rVert_p\leq\frac{p}{p-1}\lVert  g\rVert_p$$

The first inequality looks like Markov inequality. Does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: @Jack Since the two functions are positive, we can have $\mu(f\geq\epsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int f\,d\mu$

Comment: Do you know about Holder inequality?

Comment: @user160738 Yes I know. How is that related to the proof? Thanks!

Comment: Is it known that $||f||_p$ is finite?

Comment: @carmichael561 We don't know if $||f||_p$ is finite

Comment: Is the measure space $\sigma$-finite by any chance?

Comment: @LeBtz I believe it's $\sigma-$finite even though it's not mentioned in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Omega$ denote the measure space, which we assume to be $\sigma$-finite. First, we observe that

$\displaystyle\|f\|_p^p = \int_{\Omega}f^pd\mu = \int_0^\infty x^p d(f_\ast\mu)(x) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^x pt^{p-1}~dt~d(f_\ast\mu)(x)$

$\displaystyle= \int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty pt^{p-1}~d(f_\ast\mu)(x)~dt=\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\int_t^\infty d(f_\ast\mu)(x) dt = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\mu(\{f>t\})~dt$.

Using this and the given inequality, we obtain $\displaystyle\|f\|_p^p \leq \int_0^\infty\int_{\{f\geq t\}} pt^{p-2}g~d\mu~dt = \int_{\Omega}g(\omega)\int_0^{f(\omega)}pt^{p-2}~dt~d\mu(\omega)$

$\displaystyle = \int_{\Omega}\frac{p}{p-1}f(\omega)^{p-1}g(\omega)d\mu(\omega)$.

Now Hölder yields the claim.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments by John Dawkins, for this to work, we need that $f\in L^p$ (at least in the interesting case that $g\in L^p$). Otherwise $\Omega=[1,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure, $p=2,~f\equiv 1, g(x)=\frac 1x$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: Could you explain how you make the change of variables s.t. $\int_{\Omega}f^p\,d\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^p\,d(f\circ\mu)$?

Comment: @BillEphane See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure the section for change of variables. It can be proven by considering simple functions at first, then generalize.

Comment: Or we can use the Tonelli's theorem to produce the same identity: \begin{align*} \int_{\Omega} f^p(\omega) \, \mu(d\omega) &= \int_{\Omega} \bigg( \int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1}\mathbf{1}_{\{ f(\omega) > t \}} \, dt \bigg) \, \mu(d\omega) \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \bigg( \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{1}_{\{ f(\omega) > t \}} \,  \mu(d\omega) \bigg) \, dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \mu(f > t) \, dt. \end{align*}

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks!

Comment: Where is the $\sigma$-finiteness needed?

Comment: @JohnDawkins For the use of Fubini.

Comment: @LeBtz: A quibble: Your argument shows that $\|f\|_p^p\le(p/(p-1))\|f\|_p^{p/q}\|g\|_p$. But to finish you seem to need to know that $\|f\|_p<\infty$ when $\|g\|_p<\infty$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins That is a very good point actually, I edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: @LeBtz: Nice example.  Notice that on the other hand, if $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, then $f$ truncated to $f_n:=\min(f,n)$ satisfies the basic hypothesis, and is in $L^p$ for each $p>1$. It follows that $\|f_n\|_p\le(p/(p-1))\|g\|_p$ for  $n=1,2,\ldots$, so $\|f\|_p\le(p/(p-1))\|g\|_p$ by Fatou.